# Limit in Big-O in the proof of Poisson limit theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, poisson-distribution

while I was studying the proof of the Poisson limit theorem (One can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem)), I've got confused with one thing:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k + O\left(n^{k-1}\right)}{k!}\frac{\lambda^k}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}.
$$
How to show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k + O\left(n^{k-1}\right)}{k!} = 1?
$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k + O\left(n^{k-1}\right)}{k!} = \infty$ because the numerator grows without bound as $n \to \infty$ and the denominator is constant. If you look again at the wikipedia page you link to you will see that the derivation there uses $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k + O\left(n^{k-1}\right)}{n^k} = 1$ which follows directly from the definition of big-O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made an error. It should be

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^k + O\left(n^{k-1}\right)}{k!}\frac{\lambda^k}{n^k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}.
$$

Which is not difficult.

Comment: That's right! I did not saw this, I'm sorry!